# How to parse .net TimeSpam

Tags: jquery

I need to parse .net TimeSpan on jQuery, I'm trying through jQuery globalization but it doesn't working. Here is the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   context: this,
   url: "Test.asmx",
   success: function (msg) {

   }
})
```

Here is some tries onSuccess:

```
console.log($.parseDate(msg.d.MyTimeSpam));
```

It prints null

```
console.log(msg.d.MyTimeSpam);
```

It prints:

```
 Object
Days: 0
Hours: 2
Milliseconds: 0
Minutes: 0
Seconds: 0
Ticks: 72000000000
TotalDays: 0.08333333333333333
TotalHours: 2
TotalMilliseconds: 7200000
TotalMinutes: 120
TotalSeconds: 7200
__proto__: Object
```

I just want to print the time "02:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert it to a string you could do:

```
var string = ('0' + msg.d.MyTimeSpam.Hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + msg.d.MyTimeSpam.Minutes).slice(-2)
```

Comment: Ok, this way works but I mean if there is something "out of box", DateTime for example, I just do jQuery.format(date, "dd/MM")

Answer (score 0):

You've got both Hours and Minutes, can't you do something like:

```
var Time = msg.d.MyTimeSpam.Hours + ":" +  msg.d.MyTimeSpam.Minutes
```

To get leading zeros, you'll have to format each value with a function like this:

```
function pad(number, length) 
{    
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) 
    {
        str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Caveat:  I tested none of this.

Comment: Ok, this way works but I mean if there is something "out of box", DateTime for example, I just do jQuery.format(date, "dd/MM")

Comment: There are jQuery plugins floating around: http://crossbreeze.github.com/jquery-sensible-datetime/